# ¿Por qué tarda tanto en enviar un email?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Tengo un problema de tiempo de espera al enviar una serie de emails en un servicio.

Hago un bucle for con todos los usuarios y compruebo que tienen un campo boolean en `True`, si es así envia el email.

El código que uso es este:

```
html = render_to_string('email.html'{'perfil':perfil,'producto':producto,'foto':fotos[0].path, 'domain':DOMINIO})
msg = EmailMessage('concepto', html, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[usuario.email])
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

El caso es que hasta que no envía todos los correos no devuelve el `return`. No sé si existe alguna manera de hacer esto en segundo plano y que el usuario continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has dado mucha información sobre los parámetros bajos los cuales estás trabajando. Por ejemplo:

- ¿Cuánto tiempo está tardando?
- ¿Cuántos correos estás enviando?
- ¿Has revisado la consola de Django en busca de algún mensaje?

Me atrevería a decir que el problema es que estás enviando varios correos usando `send()`. Cuando usas `send()` estás abriendo una conexión al servidor de correo por cada correo que envías y eso puede estar impactando en la eficiencia.

Puedes intentar enviar los correos usando [`send_mass_email()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail). Esto abrirá una sola conexión hacia tu servidor de correos para enviarlos todos de forma masiva. La definición de `send_mass_email()` es:

```
send_mass_mail(datatuple, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None)
```

En donde `datatuple` es una tupla de tuplas y cada tupla debe tener la siguiente estructura:

```
(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

Si estás usando un bucle `for` para iterar los usuarios podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mass_email


mail_data = []
for usuario in usuarios:
    subject = 'concepto'
    message = render_to_string('email.html', {'perfil': perfil,'producto': producto,'foto': fotos[0].path,  'domain':DOMINIO})
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [usuario.email]
    mail_data.append(
        (subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
    )

send_mass_mail(tuple(email_data), fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: ahora mismo estoy mandando entre 3 y 4 emails porque no estoy en producción y tarda casi 10 segundos, por lo que pude comprobar es la conexión con el correo, estoy usando un gestor de correos propio, no es el de gmail ni hotmail, por eso creo que puede tardar un poco más pero hasta que no termina la lista de correos no acaba la función y pienso, si eso me lo hace con 3 correos, en el momento que sean 20 no me puedo imaginar cuanto puede tardar, probaré con tu ejemplo y comentaré. muchas gracias.

Comment: he conseguido solucionar el problema pero lo envía como texto plano y no como un archivo html, ¿hay alguna manera para ponerle content_subtype a send_mass_mail?